# Show/Hide Selected option from Dropdown list in IE8 not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8, hide, show

I'm trying to do a show/hide mechanism on Dropdownlist. The scenario is once the value is selected from the Dropdownlist that value should no longer available on the second Dropdownlist.

The code works on Firefox but not in IE8.
Here's the code

```
<select id="dropdownone" class="" name="dropdownone">
<option selected="selected" value="">Default</option>
<option value="1">question 1?</option>
<option value="2">question 2</option>
<option value="3">question 3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdowntwo" class="" name="dropdowntwo">
<option selected="selected" value="">Default</option>
<option value="1">question 1?</option>
<option value="2">question 2</option>
<option value="3">question 3</option>
</select>

$("#dropdownone").bind('change', function () {
            var index = this.selectedIndex;
            if (this.value != "") {
                $("#dropdowntwo option").each(function () {
                    var disabled = (this.index == index);
                    //$(this).attr("hidden", disabled);
                    if (disabled ) {
                        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    } else {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: $("#dropdownone").bind('change', function () {
 var firstDropDown = this.selectedIndex;
 
 if (this.value != "") {              
  $("#dropdowntwo option").each(function () {
   if(this.index == firstDropDown) {
    $("#dropdowntwo option[value='" + firstDropDown + "']").attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
   } else {
    $("#dropdowntwo option[value !='" + firstDropDown + "']").attr("style", "visibility: show;");
   }
  });
 }
});

I have checked in IE8 it is working fine for me.Might be this solution will help you.Plz let me know also.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
$("#dropdownone").bind('change', function () {
var firstDropDown = this.selectedIndex;

if (this.value != "") {              
    $("#dropdowntwo option").each(function () {
        if(this.index == firstDropDown) {
            $("#dropdowntwo option[value='" + firstDropDown + "']").attr("style", "visibility: hidden;");
        } else {
            $("#dropdowntwo option[value !='" + firstDropDown + "']").attr("style", "visibility: show;");
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have checked that this is working in IE8.